# Vuetify3: Close options list in v-select after selection

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

In my Vue3/Vuetify 3 application I have this v-select which contains a list with options. My problem is, that when I click and select an option, the menu stays open:

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selectedEntity"
  :items="locationAndDevices"
  label="Selector"
>
  <template #selection="item">
    {{ item.item.value.name }}
  </template>
  <template #item="{ item }">
    <v-list-item
      :title="item.value.name"
      @click="selectedEntity = item.value"
    ></v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

It is possible however, to ref the v-select and afterwards blur it:

```html
<v-list-item :title="item.value.name" @click="selectEntity(item.value)">
```

```js
selectEntity(item: DetailEntity) {
  this.selectedEntity = item;
  (this.$refs.entitySelector as HTMLElement).blur(); 
}
```

This makes the menu close. But since I will use v-select´s with this setup many places, I would like to avoid this. I would also like to avoid a `@click` handler on the `v-list-item` and let the `v-select` handle the selection. But if I remove the `@click` handler, the Vuetify styles (pointer, background hover etc.) is not applied on the `v-list-item`.

So how do you make the `v-select` close after selecting an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use objects as items, you should use the [`:item-value`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-value) prop, which gives the path to a property on each object that contains a primitive value identifying the object. This is somewhat similar to `:key`.

If you still want v-select to return the object, use the [`:return-object`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-return-object) property.

Also, you probably want to use the [`:item-title`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-title) prop, which takes the path to a property that contains the value used for the item title.

With those, you can get rid of the slots:

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selectedEntity"
  :items="locationAndDevices"
  label="Selector"
  item-value="name"
  item-title="name"
  return-object
></v-select>
```

See how it works in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    return {
      selectedEntity: ref(),
      locationAndDevices: ref([
        {name: 'item 1'},
        {name: 'item 2'},
      ]),
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-select
        v-model="selectedEntity"
        :items="locationAndDevices"
        label="Selector"
        item-value="name"
        item-title="name"
        return-object
      >
      </v-select>
      
      Selected: {{selectedEntity ?? 'none'}}
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

---

But if you still want to use the [`#item`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-item) slot, note that it passes an object named `props` as slot props. These contain the `onClick` callback, which you need to put on your v-list-item (this is what fixes your initial issue). It also contains `title`, `value` and `key` of the current item.

So if you want to stick with your `#item` slot, you have to pass these props on to the v-list-item, while overriding the `title`:

```html
<template #item="{ item, props }">
  <v-list-item
    :key="props.key"
    :title="item.raw.name"
    :value="props.value"
    @click="props.onClick"
  ></v-list-item>
</template>
```

If you are comfortable with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax), you could also just do:

```html
<template #item="{ item, props: {title, ...itemProps} }">
  <v-list-item
    :title="item.raw.name"
    v-bind="itemProps"
  ></v-list-item>
</template>
```

​
Here is another snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const locationAndDevices = [
      {name: 'item 1'},
      {name: 'item 2'},
    ]
    return {
      selectedEntity: ref(),
      locationAndDevices,
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-select
        v-model="selectedEntity"
        :items="locationAndDevices"
        label="Selector"
      >
        <template #selection="{item}">
          {{ item.raw.name }}
         </template>
        <template #item="{ item, props: {title, ...itemProps} }">
         <v-list-item
           :title="item.raw.name"
           v-bind="itemProps"></v-list-item>
       </template>
      </v-select>
      selected: {{selectedEntity ?? 'none'}}
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot - it works! (I do need the templates).
I think it´s a little hard to get a grasp on the #item props you can give the template. Do you know where I can find the documentation for it? I can´t seem to find it on the official docs..

Comment: Yes, the documentation is spotty at the moment. Just inspecting the object in the console seems to be the way to go for now. [Here is the code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f5c6a529808c8c06254fc2cc5574bd26d5abf76a/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.tsx#L332-L342) if it makes more sense

Comment: One last thing I can´t seem to figure out:
 <template #item="{ item, props: {title, ...itemProps} }">
The title prop, which holds my item, is required here, but I don´t need it. If I remove it I get console warnings:  [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "title". Expected String | Number | Boolean, got Object .

If I rename it to something else, I get console errors saying the prop is undefined.
Could this be a vuetify bug maybe?

Comment: Yes, if you remove `title` from the destructuring assignment, `itemProps` includes the title property from props, which makes `v-bind` override the value you pass in the `:title` prop. Since `props.title` contains the whole item object, this leads to a type error in v-list-item (apart from not showing the value you want to see). So the `title` variable in the destructuring assignment isn't there because you need it, but to exclude the property from `itemProps`. I have added a note to the answer, which I now realize is probably less explicit than this comment...

Comment: Ah, I see.
It´s a shame it works that way, because the linter complains about unused properties. And casting a 'title' property to an object type first, to access the actual property I need doesn´t make readable sense: 
{{ (title as DetailEntity).name }}
Maybe I should go for another solution instead of using v-list-item.
But anyways, thank you very much for the explanation :)

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have started with the destructuring, you don't have to use it. I have added the more general approach to the answer. I don't understand what you mean with casting `title`. I am pretty sure the problem came from accidentally using the `title` from props, which is an object. You don't want to cast it, you want to not use it (which you accidentally did). Not using it would solve the issue. Anyway, writing out each variable should solve the issue permanently. Downside is that you need more text and that you have to adjust it when parameters change, but I guess that's acceptable.

Comment: Awesome, I don´t use destructuring now and it works as I want it to. Guess the @click="props.onClick" was the key to my answer.  Thanks alot for your help!